Where can I find information about Hajj season travel restrictions for Jeddah airport?
I've heard rumours that during the Hajj season, there are restrictions placed on travel to Jeddah airport. For instance, this post from Pegasus Airlines on Oct 7, 2023 states that:

Saudi Arabia entry rules updates that will be applied during the Hajj Season, which will take place from May 30 to June 28.
The restrictions to be applied for our Saudi Arabia flights between the dates mentioned above are as follows;

Passengers with Hajj Visa can only be accepted on JED (Jeddah) and MED (Medina) flights.
Passengers with a Hajj visa will definitely not be accepted on RUH (Riyadh) and DMM (Dammam) flights.
Business and Commercial visa holders will definitely not be accepted on JED (Jeddah) and MED (Medina) flights.
For passengers with Government, Diplomatic, Official, Diplomatic Mission and Organization Visas, the admission processes to JED (Jeddah) and MED (Medina) flights are subject to pre-approval. Our guests with these visa types are kindly requested to arrive early at our stations where they will start their journey.


However, I can not tell the following information:

Is this a self-imposed rule applied by Pegasus Airlines or is this a rule imposed by the Saudi government?
Are the listed dates intended to apply to 2024 or 2023?

Where can I find authoritative information about such restrictions (or authoritative information that these restrictions don't exist) for someone looking to fly to Jeddah on a tourist/business visa at a time around the Hajj?

Saudia has similar rules: https://www.saudia.com/help/useful-links/legal-and-terms-and-conditions/hajj-and-umrah-travel-conditions so it's not a self-imposed rule. A

These are Saudi government restrictions to prevent people from "sneaking in" to the Hajj, which is capacity controlled.  They apply during the Islamic month of Dhu al-Hijjah, which in 2024 begins on June 7th.
They are strictly enforced by the Saudi state and will be applied equally by all airlines. Even if you somehow manage to get past the airline, you'll be stopped at Saudi immigration.
I don't think you'll be able to find any way around this on a tourist visa, other than flying to a different airport and driving to Jeddah.  If you have a business visa and a legitimate need to be in Jeddah specifically, talk to your visa sponsor, they may be able to pull strings.

What do you mean by “You can't enter Jeddah by land either”?

@NeanDerThal Right you are, corrected.
